# Error occurred while connecting to SQL Server 2012: Cannot open user database. Login failed. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4064)

Tags: sql-server

I unknowingly deleted SA user from the SQL Server 2012. Now i cannot be able to connect to the sever. It shows an error :

Cannot open user database. Login failed. Login failed for the user 'username'.(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4064)

Now i don't know what to do?

Help me please

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the DB server, and an administrator account on that machine?

Comment: Sorry, I meant do you have a Windows user account that is an administrator, and can you log in / RDP to the machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever get this error,we have to create a new user with server authentication to connect the data base

[We can create login for data base under security](http://forums.asp.net/p/1854215/5192577.aspx/1?Re%20Cannot%20open%20user%20database%20Login%20failed) tab-->create new login under it

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows administator permissions, you can restart SQL Server in single-user mode. Any administrator can then log in locally and fix things.

Give this a shot as a place to start:
[Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx)